# iteratively open files in a different directory in python3 osx

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I am an absolute novice at coding, so sorry if this is a very basic question. I am trying to open specific files in a different directory(from the current one where I am working) and make it do something. When I just ask it to find the files, it does a good job, but it wont open the files ("FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory") Iam not sure where I am going wrong. Here is my code:

```
for file_name in os.listdir("/Users/sujathakoduvayurp/Downloads/exercises-and-examples/Chapter 9/exercises"):
 if file_name.endswith(".dna"):
  print (file_name)
```

This does fine and I get the list of files with the right extension. Like so:
    xaa.dna
    xab.dna
    xac.dna
    xad.dna
    xae.dna
    xaf.dna
    xag.dna
    xah.dna
    xai.dna
    xaj.dna

But when I do this:

```
for file_name in os.listdir("/Users/sujathakoduvayurp/Downloads/exercises-and-examples/Chapter 9/exercises"):
 if file_name.endswith(".dna"):
  dna_file= open("/Users/sujathakoduvayurp/Downloads/exercises-and-examples/Chapter 9/file_name","r")
```

I get an error msg as stated before. I am not sure what the problem is. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!
PS:  I am not sure if it comes out properly here, but my indents are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with this line:

```
dna_file= open("/Users/sujathakoduvayurp/Downloads/exercises-and-example/Chapter 9/file_name","r")
```

It thinks that you are trying to open a file called `file_name` because it is included in the path string. To open the file, the path should be concatenated with the `file_name` variable instead. For example:

```
for file_name in os.listdir("/Users/sujathakoduvayurp/Downloads/exercises-and-examples/Chapter 9/exercises"):
 if file_name.endswith(".dna"):
  dna_file = open("/Users/sujathakoduvayurp/Downloads/exercises-and-examples/Chapter 9/" + file_name,"r")
```

This code should open the file since `file_name` has been removed from the path string, and is now a variable that contains the file name.

Answer (score 0):

below works for me. os.path.join

```
import os

path = "/Users/JupyterFiles/exercises and examples/working_with_the_filesystem/exercises"

for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    if file_name.endswith(".dna"):
        print(file_name)
        dna_file = open(os.path.join(path,file_name),"r")
        for line in dna_file:
            DNA = line.rstrip("\n")
            length = len(DNA)
            print(length)
```